# Can not connect nodejs micro service with spring boot application ( zuul server )

Tags: node.js, spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am trying to connect a node.js micro service with spring boot application using zuul server (api-gateway).

**zuul  application.properties :**

```
spring.application.name=api-gateway
hystrix.shareSecurityContext=true
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka


zuul.routes.node-simple.serviceId=node-simple
zuul.routes.node-simple.path=/node-simple/**

zuul.routes.home.path=/home
zuul.routes.home.url=http://localhost:8080
zuul.sensitive-headers=Cookie,Set-Cookie
server.port=8080
```

**Node js eureka configuration**

```
const client = new Eureka({
  instance: {
    id: appName,    
    instanceId: 'node',
    app: appName,
    hostName: 'localhost',
    ipAddr: '127.0.0.1',
    statusPageUrl: 'http://localhost:8200',
    port: {
      '$': PORT,
      '@enabled': 'true',
    },
    vipAddress: appName,
    dataCenterInfo: {
      '@class': 'com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo',
      name: 'MyOwn',
    }
  },
  eureka: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8761,
    servicePath: '/eureka/apps/'
  }
});
```

When I try to go to the URL of zuul (api-gateway) on eureka I am getting this error:

> Load balancer does not have available server for client: node-simple

Comment: Do you see the node js app registering with eureka?

Comment: Yes , that what  confused me !

Comment: what value are you passing in as appName?

Answer (score 0):

This is the configuration i have on my zuul setup. The zuul setup gets routing information from Eureka server

```
zuul.sensitive-headers= Cookie,Set-Cookie
zuul.strip-prefix=false
zuul.debug.request=true

spring.application.name= zuul-server
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=${EUREKA_URI:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
```

Below is my Eureka Configuration

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.server.enable-self-preservation=false
```

To be able to register a nodejs application and find it when routing requests i followed the [tutorial here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/eureka-zuul-service-discovery-dynamic-routing-javascript-microservices-node-js). Implements a connection to Eureka server and maintains the communication